# Custom UI segmented control

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I'm wondering if in IOS is possible to customize segmented control like the attached image. I have tried to change buttons image, but the segmented control container is still visible under the customized buttons. I observed that the segmented buttons title disappears if you add button image. Custom button images must include title?

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just roll your own.  Make three UIButtons with two images for each state and write logic to allow only one of them to be selected.

Comment: Take advantage of `IBOutletCollection` to have all you "segments" in an array to make it even easier.

Comment: This is a custom one, its great 
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/aksegmentedcontrol